# authorized_keys no longer working under Big Sur

Tags: macos, command-line, ssh

I use ~/.ssh/authorized_keys to allow password-less SSH connection between computers. They worked fine under macOS Catalina, but since I upgraded to macOS Big Sur they no longer work. I can log in to the other macOS all right, but I'm always asked for a password. It looks as if the server ignores my `authorized_keys` file.

I tried recreating the keys with `ssh-keygen`, removed the old `authorized_keys` file and created a new one with `ssh-copy-id`. Permissions seem fine:

```
8 -rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff   2,1K  6 oct 17:20 authorized_keys
8 -rw-------  1 xxx  staff   1,8K  9 oct 17:02 id_rsa
8 -rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff   401B  9 oct 17:02 id_rsa.pub
```

I suspect something has changed in `/etc/sshd_config`, but I can't figure out what.

**The problem exists only when I try to ssh from macOS to macOS**. From macOS to linux/ubuntu still works as expected (no password prompt).

Some interesting values from `ssh -vvv`:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
[...]
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
[...]
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
```

When I log in from macOS to Linux/Ubuntu, I see a line:

```
Server accepts key: /path/to/id_rsa RSA [...]
```

The line is missing when I try to log in from macOS to another macOS machine.

I also tried different algorithms:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

None of them worked. Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: Define "no longer work".  What is reported if you run `ssh -vvv` hostname?  If you use `ssh-copy-id` ?  Can you log in remotely at all?

Comment: I added some of the output from `ssh -vvv`. Yes, I can log in, ssh just asks for the password and seems to ignore the `authorized_keys` file. This happens in both directions (both Macs are now on Big Sur).

Comment: I'm *not* having the same problem with my Big Sur macOS machines. And, just to make sure, you've copy'n'pasted the contents of Mac1's ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub into Mac2's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file?

Comment: yes, i did `cat id_rsa.pub-from-other-machine >> .ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: And when you use `ssh-copy-id` ?

Comment: I deleted the `.ssh` directory on both machines, created a new passwordless key with `ssh-keygen` and copied the identities with `ssh-copy-id -i user@host` from either side. Still not working, I always see the password prompt.

Comment: Interestingly, I can still log in passwordlessly from macOS to unbuntu linux.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426192/macos-big-sur-does-not-accept-ssh-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the fact that I had moved my user's home directory from the usual location at `/Users/username` to a different partition at `/Volumes/Data`. (A user's home may be anywhere, it can be changed with the *Directory Utility*.) Somehow, the *sshd* did not like this. I simply moved the home one directory deeper, to `/Volumes/Data/username`. Problem gone, now I can log in with the authorized keys without password!

Comment: Wait, this isn't much of an answer. What if you need to move the home dir? Where is that configured? What error message could help figure this out? Can this issue hinder cross-platform SSHing like from Windows to MacOS?

Comment: Part of the solution may be to run `ssh-agent` on the client machine first. Then there are host HOME dir permissions. See also https://superuser.com/questions/1497657/ssh-to-macos-refuses-public-key-authentication